# How to create BitmapImage from a bmp file byte array?

Tags: c#, wpf

In my wpf application I get a byte array of a bmp file.

I want to create a new System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage.

I created MemoryStream from the byte array, but it doesn't work with SetSource.

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add reference:

```
using System.IO;
```

Use the following code.

```
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(imageArray);
Image image = Image.FromStream(ms);
```

For WPF

```
public static BitmapImage GetBitmapImage(byte[] imageArray)
{
    using (var stream = new MemoryStream(imageArray))
    {
        var bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
        bitmapImage.BeginInit();
        bitmapImage.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
        bitmapImage.StreamSource = stream;
        bitmapImage.EndInit();
        return bitmapImage;
    }
}
```

Comment: you should improve your answer using the `using` keyword, because MemoryStream is disposable

Comment: He means: using MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(imageArray){Image image = Image.FromStream(ms);}

Comment: I think is better to add using at the top to be able to use it for thee whole code. I think after loaded the bmp will be also reversed to byteArray...

Comment: Thank you for the answer but i'm using wpf and i the Image object you mean is from System.Drawing, and i cannot insert it to the image control in the xaml code.

Comment: @EricBole-Feysot: this is exactly what I meant.

Comment: Thank you its work great !! There is also a solution for silverlight ?

Comment: I found this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3335819/byte-to-bitmapimage-in-silverlight)

Comment: @OrCohen In Silverlight you would use the [SetSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapsource.setsource(v=vs.95).aspx) method.

Comment: @Clemens The problem with set source is that its not recognize byte array of a bmp file, only gif png and gpeg. Thats why im in problem.

Comment: @LPs MemoryStream is an IDisposable and should therefore be disposed, preferably by means of a `using` block.

Comment: @OrCohen How about [this suggestion](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6734402/1136211)?